# How Camel 2.11 batch aggregation works with separate route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, aggregation

First there is a similar unanswered question [Joining routes into single aggregator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584824/camel-joining-routes-into-a-single-aggregator)

We have some consumer routes (ftp, file, smb) reading files from remote systems. 
Simplified for test with direct route, but similar behavior with batch consumers:

```
from("direct:"+routeId).id(routeId)
 .setProperty(AGGREGATION_PROPERTY, constant(routeId))
 .log(String.format("Sending (${body}) to %s", "direct:start1"))
 .to("direct:aggregate");
```

After transformation all results from one poll are aggregated by batch in a separate route:

```
from("direct:aggregate")
  .aggregate(property(AGGREGATION_PROPERTY), new BodyInAggregatingStrategy())
  .completionFromBatchConsumer()
  .to("log:result", "mock:result");
```

All works fine, if every consumer runs separated. But if multiple consumers runs in parallel, aggregation will split the polls. Example if file-consumer polls 500 messages and a second route starts to read 6 files from ftp the expections is that we get 2 aggregates 1 with 500 messages from file and 1 with 6 messages from ftp.

Testcase:

```
public void testAggregateByProperty() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint result =  getMockEndpoint("mock:result");

    result.expectedBodiesReceived("A+A+A", "B+B", "A", "Z");

    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:A", "A", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 3);
    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:A", "A", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 3);
    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:B", "B", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 2);
    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:A", "A", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 3);
    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:B", "B", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 2);
    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:A", "A", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 1);
    template.sendBodyAndProperty("direct:Z", "Z", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, 7);

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
}
```

The result is: "A+A", "B", "A", "B", "A" and not the expected "A+A+A", "B+B", "A", "Z". 
Questions:

1. Is our assumption about aggregation wrong?
2. How can we achieve the expected behavior?
3. If we set completionTimeout, it seams that timeout will occur from first exchange - independent if there are still new exchanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it working. Here is the change you need (and after I will explain).

```
from("direct:aggregate").id("aggregate")
    .aggregate(property(AGGREGATION_PROPERTY), new BodyInAggregationStrategy())
    .completionSize(property(Exchange.BATCH_SIZE))
    .to("log:result", "mock:result")
```

The result will be:

```
Exchange received, body: A+A+A
Exchange received, body: B+B
Exchange received, body: A
```

Note: You won't receive a result for the `"Z"` since the batch size is `7`.

To explain - as you have read, the *Aggregator* is a versatile camel component and the key things to define correctly are:

- the aggregation expression
- the completion rule

Now in your case you are aggregating on a property `AGGREGATION_PROPERTY` which will be `A`, `B` or `Z`. In addition you are specifying a batch size.

However you aren't expressing a `completionSize()` in your route. Instead you were using `completionFromBatchConsumer` - which does something different (the code states that it looks for a `Exchange#BATCH_COMPLETE` property), thus the weird results.

Anyway, `.completionSize(Exchange.BATCH_SIZE)` will make your test run as desired.

Good luck further.

Comment: Hi @vikingsteve,
thanks for your response, meantime we found a similar solution to yours:
`.completionPredicate(simple(String.format("${property.%s} == ${property.%s}", Exchange.BATCH_SIZE, Exchange.AGGREGATED_SIZE)))`

Comment: Great, that does the same thing, though `.completionSize()` is perhaps clearer ;)